# How to display multiple db columns in DataTextField as one item not side by side in dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, sql, drop-down-menu, webforms

Database table structure: Store(id, storeName, country, region, area, continent)

On the UI under **Location** (`DropDownList`) I have to display country, area, region, continent **as a one list**. Suppose when user clicks on the Location `DropDownList` then each item should be either country or region or area or continent.

What I could see from different forums that mostly people are trying to merge data in a `DropDownList` like (firstname + lastname) as Name, where two column values displayed as one item. However, I am trying to get the opposite as below, but haven't managed yet.

Suppose, country(USA, UK), area(East, West), Region(East 1, East 2), Continent(Europe, Asia)

> **Location**
>
> USA
>   UK
>     East
>     West
>     East 1
>     Europe
>     Asia
>     ......

What I have tried so far is

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=sesqlAB\\APP;Database=BD12;user id=id;password=pwd;Persist Security Info=true;"))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select country,region,area, continent as CombinedLocation from Store", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }

        _UIDDListLocation.DataSource = dt;
        _UIDDListLocation.DataTextField = "CombinedLocation";
        _UIDDListLocation.DataValueField = "CombinedLocation";
        _UIDDListLocation.DataBind();
```

**Problem**: Using comma in the SQL statement I always get the last selected column in this case **continent** in the DropDownList. If I use + sign then I get column value side by side which I don't want it that way.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediate resolution to your problem would be to use `SQL` `UNION`. Something like this:

```
SELECT Country AS CL FROM STORE 
UNION
SELECT Region AS CL FROM STORE 
UNION
SELECT Area AS CL FROM STORE 
UNION
SELECT Continent AS CL FROM STORE
```

And then,

```
....ListLocation.DataValueField = "CL"
```